# Groupby followed by orderby keeping the group intact and then sort individual group

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

This one seemed a little tough for me to do using LINQ. I have a list of alerts and an alert looks like:

```
 public short AlertTypeId { get; set; }
 public string Type { get; set; }
 public int Severity { get; set; }
 public bool IsOverview { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Text { get; set; }
 public int Position { get; set; }
 public string Id { get; internal set; }
```

1. I want to first group these alerts by alertIDType,
2. sort elements in an individual group by severity in desc and ...
3. Then sort entire groups by the same alertIDType in a specific order (I have a utils sorter for that mentioned below)

The sorting code currently looks like:

```
var alerts = new BPAlerts
        {
            AllAlerts = intakeAlerts.Select(
                alert => new BPAlert
                {
                    AlertTypeId = alert.AlertTypeId ?? 8100,
                    IsOverview = alert.IsOverviewAlert.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    Text = alert.AlertText,
                    Title = alert.AlertTitle,
                    Type = alert.AlertTypeId == 8106 ? "warning" : "report",
                    Severity = alert.AlertSeverity.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    Position = alert.Position.GetValueOrDefault()
                }).ToList()
        };

        alerts.AllAlerts = alerts.AllAlerts.GroupBy(a => a.AlertTypeId)
                .OrderByDescending(g => Utils.AlertSorterUtil.SortByAlertTypeId(g.Key))
                .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Severity)).ToList();

        // Alerts displayed on the overview page
        alerts.OverviewAlerts =
            alerts.AllAlerts
                .ToList()
                .Where(a => a.IsOverview && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Title))
                .Take(3)
                .ToList();
```

Utils sorter method looks like:

```
public class AlertSorterUtil
{
    public static int SortByAlertTypeId(short alertTypeId)
    {
        var orderArray = new int[]
        {
            8106,   // Confirmed Out of Business
            8105,   // Bankruptcy
            8111,   // Lack of Licensing
            8109,   // Investigations
            8103,   // Government Actions
            8104,   // Pattern of Complaints
            8112,   // Customer Reviews
            8110,   // Accreditation
            8101,   // Misuse of BBB Name
            8107,   // Advisory
            8102,   // Advertising Review
        };

        for (int orderValue = 0; orderValue < orderArray.Length; orderValue++)
        {
            if (alertTypeId == orderArray[orderValue])
            {
                return orderValue;
            }
        }

        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `GroupBy`? I don't see your attempt to group these in your post.

Comment: yes I have. what after group by? how do you sort elements of individual group? and then re arrange whole groups based of their alertID grouping property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of alerts to perform all these operations on. do the following with LINQ. It will group alerts by AlertTypeId then sort the groups by AlertTypeId and finally sort individual groups by Severity asc.

```
var groupedAlerts = alerts.GroupBy(a => a.AlertTypeId).OrderBy(g => Utils.AlertSorterUtil.SortByAlertTypeId(g.Key)).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Severity).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you :) but for sorting the groups I have a custom logic using my util method I have mentioned above: do I need to do "var groupedAlerts = alerts.GroupBy(a => a.AlertTypeId).OrderBy(g => Utils.AlertSorterUtil.SortByAlertTypeId(g.Key) ).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Severity).ToList()).ToList();"

Comment: My mistake. in my above comment I need to sort individual elements of a group by severity and individual groups by alertID. Can you edit your answer to reflect the change?

Comment: Isn't doing the same already, groups are ordered by AlertTypeId and elements in each group are ordered by Severity?

Comment: .OrderBy(g => g.Key) was it that doing? I am sorry I am new to C# and find it hard to read linq sometimes

Comment: the .OrderBy(g => g.Key) part is sorting the groups, you want me to use Utils.AlertSorterUtil.SortByAlertTypeId function to sort the groups in the answer?

Comment: If you can do that it will be great help :) Thank you!

Comment: Sure. Let me run a few tests and once done I will. I am sure a lot of people can help from this :)

Comment: Approved. Thank you again.

Comment: Hey man one quick question. How do I assign it to AllAlerts in my alerts object?

Comment: what is type of AllAlerts?

Comment: List<BPAlert> type

Comment: groupedAlerts in the solution is List<List<BPAlert>>, list of lists because we have grouped them, so each group represents a list. you can't directly assign this result to AllAlerts.

Comment: so what should I do? I cannot assign this to alerts

Comment: can I use SelectMany?

Comment: where do you have to use AllAlerts, have to show on some view?

Comment: No. Not on this page. I just build this object and react does the rest

Comment: You can use selectMany like: AllAlerts=groupedAlerts.SelectMany(g => g).ToList();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198901/discussion-between-rashid-ali-and-ackman).